# Find total time worked with multiple jobs / orders with overlap / overlapping times on each worker and job / order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I searched night and day back when I was first starting out in the sql world for an answer to this question. Could not find anything similar to this for my needs so I decided to ask and answer my own question in case others need help like I did.

Here is an example of the data I have. For simplicity, it is all from the Job table. Each JobID has it's own Start and End time that are basically random and can overlap, have gaps, start and end at the same time as other jobs etc.

```
--Available--
JobID  WorkerID  JobStart             JobEnd
1      25        '2012-11-17 16:00'  '2012-11-17 17:00'
2      25        '2012-11-18 16:00'  '2012-11-18 16:50'
3      25        '2012-11-19 18:00'  '2012-11-19 18:30'
4      25        '2012-11-19 17:30'  '2012-11-19 18:10'
5      26        '2012-11-18 16:00'  '2012-11-18 17:10'
6      26        '2012-11-19 16:00'  '2012-11-19 16:50'
```

What I wanted the result of the query to show would be:

```
WorkerID  TotalTime(in Mins)
25        170
26        120
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the overlaps need to be ignored. Basically this is supposed to treat these workers and their jobs like you would an hourly employee and not a contractor. Like if I worked two jobIDs and started and finished them both from 12:00pm to 12:30pm, as an employee I would only get paid for 30 mins, whereas a contractor would likely get paid 60 mins, since their jobs are treated individually and get paid per job. The point of this query is to analyze jobs in a database that are tied to a worker, and need to find out if that worker was treated as an employee, what would his total hours worked in a given set of time come out to be.

EDIT2: won't let me answer my own question for 7 hours, will move it there later.

Ok, Answering Question now. Basically, I use temp table to build each minute between the min and max datetime of the jobs I am looking up.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#time') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
drop table #time
END
DECLARE @FromDate AS DATETIME,
     @ToDate AS DATETIME,
     @Current AS DATETIME
SET @FromDate = '2012-11-17 16:00'
SET @ToDate = '2012-11-19 18:30'

create table #time  (cte_start_date datetime)
set @current = @FromDate
while (@current < @ToDate)
begin

insert into #time (cte_start_date)
values (@current)

set @current = DATEADD(n, 1, @current)

end
```

Now I have all the mins in a temp table. Now I need to join all the Job table info into it and select out what I need in one go.

```
SELECT J.WorkerID
,COUNT(DISTINCT t.cte_start_date) AS TotalTime
FROM #time AS t
INNER JOIN Job AS J ON t.cte_start_date >= J.JobStart AND t.cte_start_date < J.JobEnd --Thanks ErikE
GROUP BY J.WorkerID --Thanks Martin Parkin

drop table #time
```

That is the very simplified answer and is good to get someone started.

Comment: Nice solution, but I looked at what you did and put it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/898de/18). It does not quite work as you hoped, but is close.  Also you had en error where you missed `GROUP BY J.WorkerID` in your `SELECT` query.  Take a look.

Comment: Thanks man, damn Group By :). I love how many times I see 'incorrect syntax near the keyword ',' lol. Also, I have never used SQL Fiddle, that is a pretty badass tool, again, thank you!

Comment: A pleasure - I'm glad you got to the bottom of your query!

Comment: icvader, the simple tweak of `t.cte_start_date >= J.JobStart AND t.cte_start_date < J.JobEnd` instead of your `BETWEEN` clause will repair your query. (See @MartinParkin 's fiddle showing 172 and 122 minutes as the results your query currently gives.)

Comment: And one more comment: your query works, but will perform very badly as the range of time the jobs cover becomes large. Putting a year's worth of minutes into a table is going to take quite a bit of time and space...

Comment: @ErikE: Oh trust me I know, I had to run it across 3 years with over 10K Workers, over 3.7M jobs. For my purposes, since I work for a 24/7 company, I need every minute on the table anyways. I am actually contemplating building a permanent minute table so I don’t have to keep building a massive temp table, then maybe having it horizontally partitioned every yearly quarter or something.

Comment: How does my query below perform on that big dataset? Why do you need all minutes anyway?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to run your query yet, I am very interested, It's just that my example here is an extreme simplification lol. For my query and data, I need every minute in the temp table because we have workers working every minute of the day. It is highly unlikely for us to have someone not working in any given minute of any given day. I really want to try your query, and once I write it for my data I will let you know how they compare. I may make yours the answer to my question. I love SQL, I once heard if you don't look at your old code and laugh, you aren't getting better.

Comment: Great, I'd love to hear the results. (btw: please tag me with @ErikE when we're not the only commenters or I won't know you've sent me a message). Note that my query doesn't use the "every minute" thing because it doesn't need to: it only concerns itself with the actual start or end times found in the table for each WorkerID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query does the job as well. Its performance is very good (while the execution plan looks not so great, the actual CPU and IO beat many other queries).

[See it working in a Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60e99/1).

```
WITH Times AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT
      H.WorkerID,
      T.Boundary
   FROM
      dbo.JobHistory H
      CROSS APPLY (VALUES (H.JobStart), (H.JobEnd)) T (Boundary)
), Groups AS (
   SELECT
      WorkerID,
      T.Boundary,
      Grp = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY T.WorkerID ORDER BY T.Boundary) / 2
   FROM
      Times T
      CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (1)) X (Dup)
), Boundaries AS (
   SELECT
      G.WorkerID,
      TimeStart = Min(Boundary),
      TimeEnd = Max(Boundary)
   FROM
      Groups G
   GROUP BY
      G.WorkerID,
      G.Grp
   HAVING
      Count(*) = 2
)
SELECT
   B.WorkerID,
   WorkedMinutes = Sum(DateDiff(minute, 0, B.TimeEnd - B.TimeStart))
FROM
   Boundaries B
WHERE
   EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.JobHistory H
      WHERE
         B.WorkerID = H.WorkerID
         AND B.TimeStart < H.JobEnd
         AND B.TimeEnd > H.JobStart
   )
GROUP BY
   WorkerID
;
```

With a clustered index on `WorkerID, JobStart, JobEnd, JobID`, and with the sample 7 rows from the above fiddle a template for new worker/job data repeated enough times to yield a table with 14,336 rows, here are the performance results. I've included the other working/correct answers on the page (so far):

```
Author  CPU  Elapsed  Reads   Scans
------  ---  -------  ------  -----
  Erik  157    166      122       2
Gordon  375    378    106964  53251
```

I did a more exhaustive test from a different (slower) server (where each query was run 25 times, the best and worst values for each metric were thrown out, and the remaining 23 values were averaged) and got the following:

```
Query     CPU   Duration  Reads   Notes
--------  ----  --------  ------  ----------------------------------
Erik 1    215   231       122     query as above
Erik 2    326   379       116     alternate technique with no EXISTS
Gordon 1  578   682       106847  from j
Gordon 2  584   673       106847  from dbo.JobHistory
```

The alternate technique I thought to be sure to improve things. Well, it saved 6 reads, but cost a lot more CPU (which makes sense). Instead of carrying through the start/end statistics of each timeslice to the end, it is best just recalculating which slices to keep with the `EXISTS` against the original data. It may be that a different profile of few workers with many jobs could change the performance statistics for different queries.

In case anyone wants to try it, use the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements from my fiddle and then run this 11 times:

```
INSERT dbo.JobHistory
SELECT
   H.JobID + A.MaxJobID,
   H.WorkerID + A.WorkerCount,
   DateAdd(minute, Elapsed + 45, JobStart),
   DateAdd(minute, Elapsed + 45, JobEnd)
FROM
   dbo.JobHistory H
   CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT
         MaxJobID = Max(JobID),
         WorkerCount = Max(WorkerID) - Min(WorkerID) + 1,
         Elapsed = DateDiff(minute, Min(JobStart), Min(JobEnd))
      FROM dbo.JobHistory
   ) A
;
```

I built two other solutions to this query but the best one with about double the performance had a fatal flaw (not correctly handling fully enclosed time ranges). The other had very high/bad statistics (which I knew but had to try).

**Explanation**

Using all the endpoint times from each row, build up a distinct list of all possible time ranges of interest by duplicating each endpoint time and then grouping in such a way as to pair each time with the next possible time. Sum the elapsed minutes of these ranges wherever they coincide with any actual worker's working time.

Comment: . . Since you are testing performance, can you make a minor change to my query to see how it works?  The innermost `from j` in the main query can really be `from jobs` -- it doesn't need to calculate the overlap flag.  This should probably save a bit of time on my query, because SQL Server runs the CTE each time it is referenced.

Comment: I should be able to do that later tonight!

Comment: . . I'm not convinced that your methods generalizes.  When the groups consist of a start and end, it makes sense.  But when a group is two starts or two ends, I'm suspicious.  It seems to me like you would need to keep the information on whether something is a start or end through the process.  This is just a nagging feeling; your version could be 100% correct.

Comment: Testing results: The execution plans are identical, statistics have no consistent or significant difference, after changing `from j` to `from jobs`. Regarding my method, could you modify the fiddle to present the most tricky data you can think of? I'd be happy for you to expose a flaw in my query so I may correct it. As for me, I'm 100% confident it is correct. :) To address it logically: all I care about is each interval. I calculate all those, throw out the ones that don't have a job running at that time, and then sum. `7:00 - 9:00, 8:00 - 9:00` becomes `7:00 - 8:00, 8:00 - 9:00`. It works.

Answer (score 1):

A query such as the following should provide the answer you are looking for:

```
SELECT  WorkerID,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, JobStart, JobEnd)) AS TotalTime
  FROM  Job
  GROUP BY WorkerID
```

Apologies that it is untested (I have no SQL Server to test it here) but it should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, answered a little fast. I forgot to put in my question that this is supposed to be treated like it was ignoring the overlaps and just looking for the total time worked as if the jobs were done like an employee would do. Like if I worked two jobs, and they both started and finished from 12:00pm to 12:30pm on the same day, as an employee, I am only getting paid for 30 mins, not 60 mins. I am editing my Question now, otherwise what you have would work as a sum up for each job all together.

Comment: Ah not a problem, I'll take another look and see whether I can answer your revised query :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated query.  Explanation follows.

```
with j as (
     select j.*,
            (select 1
             from jobs j2
             where j2.workerid = j.workerid and
                   j2.starttime < j.endtime and
                   j2.starttime > j.starttime
            ) as HasOverlap
     from jobs j
    )
select workerId,
       sum(datediff(minute, periodStart, PeriodEnd)) as NumMinutes
from (select workerId, min(startTime) as periodStart, max(endTime) as PeriodEnd
      from (select j.*,
                   (select min(starttime)
                    from j j2
                    where j2.workerid = j.workerid and
                          j2.starttime >= j.starttime and
                          j2.HasOverlap is null
                   ) as thegroup
            from j
           ) j
      group by workerId, thegroup
     ) j
group by workerId;
```

The key to understanding this approach is to understand the "overlap" logic.  One time period overlaps with the next when the next start time is before the previous end time.  By assigning an overlap flag to each record, we know if it overlaps with the "next" record.  The above logic is using the start time for this.  It might be better to use the JobId, especially if two jobs for the same worker could start at the same time.

The calculation of the overlap flag uses a correlated subquery (this is `j` in the `with` clause).

Then, for each record we go back and find the first record afterwards where the `overlap` value is NULL.  This provides a grouping key for all records in a given overlap set.

The rest, then, is just to aggregate the results, first at the `workerId`/group level and then at the `workerId` level to get the final results.

I have not run this SQL, so it might have syntax errors.